# Hiding Adobe Toolbars, menubars, scrollbar, etc

Tags: vb.net, acrobat

I am using the "Adobe Acrobat 7.0 Browser Control Type Library 1.0" control to view PDF's in my vb.net application. I want it to show just the PDF with no menus and toolbars. I have used the following code:

```
AxAcroPDF1.LoadFile("C:\ShippingForm.pdf")
AxAcroPDF1.src = "C:\ShippingForm.pdf"
AxAcroPDF1.setShowToolbar(False)
AxAcroPDF1.setView("fitH")
AxAcroPDF1.setLayoutMode("SinglePage")
AxAcroPDF1.setShowScrollbars(False)

AxAcroPDF1.Show()
```

I am still getting the Navigation Panel on the left side of the panel. Does anybody have information on which method would disable this or maybe a list of all the methods? A google search didn't get me anywhere.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe that you need:

```
AxAcroPDF1.setPageMode("none")
```

This turns off thumbnails and bookmarks.

There is a decent reference document located [here](http://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/en/acrobat/sdk/pdf/iac/IACReference.pdf).